# How to show results from second table that doesn't appear in first table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables "Films" and "Tickets"

Let's say I have ID_Film: 1,2,3,4 and Foreign key in "Tickets" that have ID_Film: 1,2.

I want to display Title of films that aren't in "Tickets", so with ID 3 and 4.

Here's what I tried, but it displays no records and the result is empty

```
SELECT Films.Title_Film 
FROM Films INNER JOIN Tickets ON Films.ID_Film=Tickets.ID_Film
WHERE Tickets.ID_Film NOT IN
(
  SELECT ID_Film FROM Films
)
```

Comment: get rid of the join

Comment: See about the different kinds of JOINs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you don't need the inner join, just the query below will suffice.

```
SELECT Films.Title_Film
FROM Films
WHERE Films.ID_Film NOT IN
(
   SELECT ID_Film FROM Tickets
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use JOIN and modify the WHERE clause of your query. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT Films.Title_Film FROM Films WHERE Films.ID_Film NOT IN
(
 SELECT ID_Film FROM Tickets
);
```